# How to make curl await for response and then continue execute code

Tags: bash, ubuntu, curl

I have a simple code:

```
HEADERS_FILE_NAME=headers.txt
FILE=body.xml

echo "start getting"
curl -D $HEADERS_FILE_NAME -o $FILE --fail http://<SOMEURLHERE>:7001/articles?indexingInfoId=4&format=xml 2>/dev/null
echo "end getting"
```

The output is:

```
start getting
end getting
root@prod_l04:~#   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  166M    0  166M    0     0  14.5M      0 --:--:--  0:00:11 --:--:-- 34.9M
```

Question: how to make curl await when response will be received, and then execute "`echo "end getting"`"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL is unquoted and contains an ampersand (`&`); so the shell reads that line as:

```
curl -D $HEADERS_FILE_NAME -o $FILE --fail http://:7001/articles?indexingInfoId=4 & format=xml 2>/dev/null
```

and thus runs `curl` at the background. Since `format=xml 2>/dev/null` is a valid command line you're not getting an error from it.

See
[Bash Reference Manual § Quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) and,
[Bash Reference Manual § Lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html#Lists)
for further information.

And here is a working, safe version of your script with proper quotation:

```
HEADERS_FILE_NAME='headers.txt'
FILE='body.xml'

echo 'start getting'
curl -D "$HEADERS_FILE_NAME" -o "$FILE" --fail 'http://<SOMEURLHERE>:7001/articles?indexingInfoId=4&format=xml' 2>/dev/null
echo 'end getting'
```